# Error in launching RTAB node in ROS Melodic

Tags: ros

I know I should ask this one in ROS Forums but I couldn't due to some reasons (Sorry for that). So the thing is, I built standalone RTAB package from source in my Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) with ROS Melodic installed. I am trying to launch the node for rtab mapping by writing this in my sourced catkin workspace:

```
~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros-master/launch rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" rtabmapviz:=false rviz:=true
```

But when i do this it raises RLE Exception Error **even though the path given to rtabmap.launch file is correct and file is at the location**. Error is something like that:

```
RLException: [rtabmap.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rtabmap_ros-master] nor is [rtabmap_ros-master] a launch file name
```

I don't know why its giving this same error and i am stuck here. Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests it can not find a launch file for that package. This is usually caused by one of two things. The first is you need to make sure you're sourcing the correct setup file; here it would be `source ~/catkin_ws/setup.bash`

The second thing is that you need to make sure you're actually *installing* the launch files so that they can be used when built. Here that would mean your `CMakeLists.txt` has something like this:

```
install(DIRECTORY launch/
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```